# Selections (Turing)

Tags: turing-lang

I am learning Turing right now. We are currently making a program about having input three marks, get the two highest marks, then find the average of the two marks. I did the code right, but it's very long and not efficient at all. I need a way to shorten this code:

```
%Variables and Contants

var rfirstmark : real
var rsecondmark : real
var rthirdmark : real
var rfirsthigh : real
var rsecondhigh : real
var rthirdhigh : real
var raverage : real
const camount := 2

%Input

put "Enter the first mark."
get rfirstmark
put ""

put "Enter the second mark."
get rsecondmark
put ""

put "Enter the third mark."
get rthirdmark
put ""

%Process

if rfirstmark > rsecondmark then
    if rfirstmark > rthirdmark then
        rfirsthigh := rfirstmark
    end if
end if

if rfirstmark > rthirdmark then
    if rfirstmark > rsecondmark then
        rfirsthigh := rfirstmark
    end if
end if

if rfirstmark < rsecondmark then
    if rfirstmark > rthirdmark then
        rsecondhigh := rfirstmark
    end if
end if

if rfirstmark < rthirdmark then
    if rfirstmark > rsecondmark then
        rsecondhigh := rfirstmark
    end if
end if

if rfirstmark < rsecondmark then
    if rfirstmark < rthirdmark then
        rthirdhigh := rfirstmark
    end if
end if

if rfirstmark < rthirdmark then
    if rfirstmark < rsecondmark then
        rthirdhigh := rfirstmark
    end if
end if

if rsecondmark > rfirstmark then
    if rsecondmark > rthirdmark then
        rfirsthigh := rsecondmark
    end if
end if

if rsecondmark > rthirdmark then
    if rsecondmark > rfirstmark then
        rfirsthigh := rsecondmark
    end if
end if

if rsecondmark < rfirstmark then
    if rsecondmark > rthirdmark then
        rsecondhigh := rsecondmark
    end if
end if

if rsecondmark < rthirdmark then
    if rsecondmark > rfirstmark then
        rsecondhigh := rsecondmark
    end if
end if

if rsecondmark < rfirstmark then
    if rsecondmark < rthirdmark then
        rthirdhigh := rsecondmark
    end if
end if

if rsecondmark < rthirdmark then
    if rsecondmark < rfirstmark then
        rthirdhigh := rsecondmark
    end if
end if

if rthirdmark > rfirstmark then
    if rthirdmark > rsecondmark then
        rfirsthigh := rthirdmark
    end if
end if

if rthirdmark > rsecondmark then
    if rthirdmark > rfirstmark then
        rfirsthigh := rthirdmark
    end if
end if

if rthirdmark < rfirstmark then
    if rthirdmark > rsecondmark then
        rsecondhigh := rthirdmark
    end if
end if

if rthirdmark < rsecondmark then
    if rthirdmark > rfirstmark then
        rsecondhigh := rthirdmark
    end if
end if

if rthirdmark < rfirstmark then
    if rthirdmark < rsecondmark then
        rthirdhigh := rthirdmark
    end if
end if

if rthirdmark < rsecondmark then
    if rthirdmark < rfirstmark then
        rthirdhigh := rthirdmark
    end if
end if

raverage := (rfirsthigh + rsecondhigh) / camount

%Output

put "The average of the two highest marks is " ..
put raverage
```

I need a way to shorten the process part without using and/or (Because that's what our teacher said).

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a [`for loop`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Turing/Loops).

Comment: Thanks, but this might sound stupid. How do you use for loop in this situation? I'm new to Turing, and programming most of all.

Comment: I've never used Turing myself, so unfortunately can't give you much extra guidance than that. It's certainly a `for` loop that you're looking for though - there might be better examples floating around online :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an array and then [sorting it](http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=447).